# JOLT add object name into body

Tags: json, parsing, jolt, jsonparser

I have a JSON Payload and I would like to use the name of each repeating object and add it to the body :

```json
{
  "error": [],
  "result": {
    "trades": {
      "foo-test-UCI7BS": {
        "ordertxid": "00TEST",
        "postxid": "00TEST"
      },
      "foo-test-3FKGH6": {
        "ordertxid": "00TEST",
        "postxid": "00TEST"
      }
    },
    "count": 2346
  }
}
```

**Expected output** with object names within the body, this is a repeating element so needs to be dynamically added:

```json
{
  "trades": [
    {
      "ordertxid": "00TEST",
      "postxid": "00TEST",
      "ID": "foo-test-UCI7BS"
    },
    {
      "ordertxid": "00TEST",
      "postxid": "00TEST",
      "ID": "foo-test-3FKGH6"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have already been successful in getting the array but I need the object name to be included within the body

```json
{
  "trades": [
    {
      "ordertxid": "00TEST",
      "postxid": "00TEST"
    },
    {
      "ordertxid": "00TEST",
      "postxid": "00TEST"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Spec**:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "result": {
        "trades": {
          "*": "trades"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `$` symbol in order to grab key names of the each objects, and get rid of them within the second shift transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "result": {
        "trades": {
          "*": {
            "@": "&2[0].&",
            "$": "&2[0].&.ID"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "trades"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]