# Add json object key as value

Tags: json, jolt

I have a JSON:

```json
{
  "error" : {
    "code" : "validation_failed",
    "message" : "Validation failed",
    "fields" : {
      "date_end" : {
        "code" : "min_value",
        "message" : "Value is less than minimum allowed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`date_end` can be `date_start`, `name`, `geo`. I need to extract `message`, I did this:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "error": {
        "fields": {
          "date_end|date_start|name|geo": {
            "message": "message"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But also I need this json object name inside `message`. So I expect to get this result:

```json
{
  "message": "date_end|Value is less than minimum allowed"
}
```

Before `message` I need to add this json object name. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70940611/jolt-add-object-name-into-body ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following transformation specs :

```json
[
  { // convert message attribute to an array with two components 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "error": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "fields": {
          "*": {
            "*": "&3.&2.&1.&",
            "$|message": "&3.&2.&1.message"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // concatenate those components of the array
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "error": {
        "fields": {
          "*": {
            "message": "=join('|',@(1,&))"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```